# A shorter way of saying "In view of the fact"

Tags: translation, spanish

I need a shorter, equivalent form for "In view of the fact". I am a certified Spanish/English translator in Venezuela. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: "Given" is a common "formal" term.

Comment: This form fits better in the context of the document I am working. Thanks to all that took some time to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inasmuch as** may be a good choice in a formal context.

> From [**Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inasmuch-as) - in view of the fact that; seeing that; since
>   The outcome was important **inasmuch as** it showed just what human beings were capable of.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome, Elpidio!

Use *because*.

Comment: "considering" or "seeing as" might also work

Comment: Inasmuch as, considering, since, etc.